# Trying to hide a node after contact was made

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I have a SKSprite node that I want to make disappear after contact was made. I tried to set the .hidden = true but this did not work

```
var coin = SKSpriteNode()
//MARK: SKPhysicsContactDelegate methods

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == userCategory) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == objectCategory) {

        gameOver = 1
        movingObjects.speed = 0
        presentGameOverView()

    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == userCategory) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == coinCategory) {

        println("scoring")
        //code to hide node
        coin.hidden = true //not working

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see where you set the `hidden` property to true. Can you post that code as well?

Comment: Are you able to log "scoring" so you know your malfunctioning code is actually being run.

Comment: yes i am able to log it @meisenman

Comment: you should probably be accessing the coin by casting one of the contact.bodies as a spritenode and hiding it that way.  Otherwise, you could simply remove the coin.

Comment: coin.removeFromParent() did not work and I get an error 
var coin = contact.bodyB as SKSpriteNode (SKPhysicsBody is not convertible to SKSpriteNode) @meisenman

Comment: You forgot the .node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SKPhysicsBody` has a property called `node`. This can be accessed inside the `didContactBegin` function to hide the `node`.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == userCategory) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == coinCategory) {

        println("scoring")
        //code to hide node
        contact.bodyB.node?.hidden = true // Changed

    }
}
```